# How to draw UIViews in ARKit?

Tags: arkit

I want to place content in an ARKit scene that I would normally draw in a UIView. I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

I know how to create something like that in a UIView, straightforward, but, what are the proper steps to place 2D content like shown in the image in the 3D scene, so it looks clear, sharp and things perform well?

Comment: It seems like this is not the right way of thinking. The answer given by @joshRobbins is helpful to see how to somehow stick a UIView on the texture of the 3D object, but the layout of the UIView subviews does not play along. So, the solution as given is not working for me. I'll move on and approach the problem differently. This doesn't seem to be the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 4):

A `UIView` can be rendered as an `SCNGeometry`'s Material.

Here is a very basic example which should get you started:

```
/// Creates An SCNNode With A Plane Geometry & UIView As A Material
func createUIViewOnNode(){

    //1. Create An Empty Node
    let holderNode = SCNNode()

    //2. Set It's Geometry As An SCNPlane
    holderNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 0.6, height: 0.3)

    //2. Create A New Material
    let material = SCNMaterial()

    //3. Create A UIView As A Holder For Content
    let viewToAdd = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))
    viewToAdd.backgroundColor = .white

    //4. Create Two Subviews
    let redView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
    redView.backgroundColor = .red
    viewToAdd.addSubview(redView)

    let cyanView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 110, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
    cyanView.backgroundColor = .cyan
    viewToAdd.addSubview(cyanView)

    //5. Set The Materials Contents
    material.diffuse.contents = viewToAdd

    //6. Set The 1st Material Of The Plane
    holderNode.geometry?.firstMaterial = material
    material.isDoubleSided = true

    //7. Add To The Scene & Position It
    augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(holderNode)

    holderNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)
}
```

Comment: makes sense. Is this going to render the view crisp? Have you done this before? Thanks

Comment: Personally I have never had the need to do so :) And regarding crispness you will just have to experiment :)

Comment: You could also create a template .scn and access the nodes and change the content dynamically :) that would probably look better :)

Comment: I have a custom view I'm trying to do the same thing but it doesn't work. The view shows but not the contents. I have labels and images within it